# compile angular on an element after angular compilation has already happened

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm writing a directive and when clicked it loads a html template from the server.  How can I get angular to compile this?

EDIT: I should probably mention the template is used for loading into a modal.

Comment: a jsfiddle would be very nice

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can inject the $compile service and $compile it whenever you want. `$compile('<p>{{total}}</p>')(scope)` is the example from the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile).

In practice you'll probably want to do something like this:

```
//Example as a directive's link function
function link(scope, element, attributes){
  scope.name = "world";
  template = "<p>hello {{name}}</p>"; //this could come from anywhere
  element.html(template);
  $compile(element.contents())(scope);
}
```

This example appends the compiled contents instead of replacing it:

```
function link(scope, element, attributes){
  scope.something = "this is bananas";
  $compile("<p>{{something}}</p>")(scope, function(cloned, scope){
    element.append(cloned);
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm not getting an error when doing this, but the template is also not being compiled.  The controller that I am calling in the template is getting run however.

Comment: Sorry I was typing from memory and forgot one bit, `contents()` because you don't want to pass the element, but only its contents. I edited it now it should work. Here's a working example in plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/M5np1QTZgcGuQOfeIHca?p=preview (click on app.js on the left side to see the code)

Comment: Thanks, this is getting pretty close.  The only thing is I don't want to use the element of the directive, I'm basically creating a new one and passing it to a modal call.  Is there a way to grab the result of a compile so that I can pass it to my modal plugin call?

Comment: Yes `var clonedElement = $compile(templateHTML)(scope, function(clonedElement, scope) {
  //attach the clone to DOM document at the right place
});`

Comment: To clarify, the second argument after scope in the resulting function of $compile is a callback that gives you a cloned version of the element which you can then insert into your modal. That's called a `cloneAttachedFn`  This is pretty well documented in the docs which is linked in my original answer.

Comment: I also just updated the plnkr to show you how to use it that way.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  I finally got it.  My problem was that instead of putting the compile part into a function on the scope, I was putting it directly in the link using an element.bind('click'... call.  Thanks again!