# Angular.js compile all directives contained in a text

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-compile

My application is loading a bunch of text with `$http` into a `<div>`. Within that text there might be angular directives:

```
<div id="div1"> 
    blah blah 
    <my-directive attribute="123"> some text </my-directive> 
    blah blah
</div>
```

`<my-directive>` is included in the code of my application but it behaves as simple text. I understand it's normal since it would have to be compiled first. But I don't know how to do that easily (I can only think of parsing the text with regular expressions, compile the found directives one by one into new elements, and re-append the whole thing in the right order, which seems complicated).

What is the best way to compile all directives in div1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the angular documentation, [ng-include](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) "fetches, compiles and includes an external HTML fragment."

[Here is a demo](http://plnkr.co/azGFFaPxKS0iGag2wpdR), using your example text.

Comment: Thanks, that actually answers my question. For people who need do do the same thing at runtime (once the page is already rendered by angular, e.g. if the text is loaded via ajax by the user), look at this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064543/compile-angular-on-an-element-after-angular-compilation-has-already-happened